# Computing with a finite subset of an infinite representation in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a function `Z -> Z -> whatever` which I treat as a sort of a map from `(Z, Z)` to `whatever`, let's type it as `FF`.

With `whatever` being a simple sum constructible from `nix` or `inj_whatever`.

This map I initialize with some data, in the fashion of:

```
Definition i (x y : Z) (f : FF) : FF :=
  fun x' y' =>
    if andb (x =? x') (y =? y')
    then inj_whatever
    else f x y.
```

The `=?` represents boolean decidable equality on `Z`, from Coq's `ZArith`.

Now I would like to have equality on two of such `FF`s, I don't mind invoking `functional_extensionality`. What I would like to do now is to have Coq computationally decide equality of two `FF`s.

For example, suppose we do something along the lines of:

`Definition empty : FF := fun x y => nix.`

Now we add some arbitrary values to make `foo` and `foo'`, those are equivalent under functional extensionality:

`Definition foo := i 0 0 (i 0 (-42) (i 56 1 empty)).`
`Definition foo' := i 0 (-42) (i 56 1 (i 0 0 empty)).`

What is a good way to automatically have Coq determine `foo = foo'`. `Ltac` level stuff? Actual terminating computation? Do I need domain restriction to a finite one?

The domain restriction is a bit of an intricate one. I manipulate the maps in a way `f : FF -> FF`, where `f` can extend the subset of `Z x Z` that the computation is defined on. As such, come to think of it, it can't be `f : FF -> FF`, but more like `f : FF -> FF_1` where `FF_1` is a subset of `Z x Z` that is extended by a small constant. As such, when one applies `f` n times, one ends up with `FF_n` which is equivalent to domain restriction of `FF` plus `n * constant` to the domain. So the function `f` slowly (by a constant factor) expands the domain FF is defined on.

Comment: To say it softly, your question is extremely vague, so it is hard to figure out _whatever_ you would like to do, much less to propose a solution. Please provide a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example".

Comment: @ejgallego You're absolutely right, I've made an attempt to mend the situation with a simple example.

Comment: It is still too vague for my taste, for example you are missing out some details, such as the needed equality on "_whatever_" etc... That being said, for functions "A -> B", where "A" is a finite type, first, extensionality holds without axioms if you know how to canonically represent them, and second, yes, you can reflect equality of such functions to computational equality without too much pain if you use the proper framework.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): it's a PITA to start experimenting when you have to guess the imports (where does `?=` come from?) and fill in the blanks (`whatever` / `inj_whatever`).

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment more specifics are needed in order to elaborate a satisfactory answer. See the below example --- intended for a step by step description --- on how to play with equality on restricted function ranges using mathcomp:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

(* We need this in order for the computation to work. *)
Section AllU.
Variable n : nat.

(* Bounded and unbounded fun *)
Definition FFb := {ffun 'I_n -> nat}.

Implicit Type (f : FFb).

Lemma FFP1 f1 f2 : reflect (f1 = f2) [forall x : 'I_n, f1 x == f2 x].
Proof. exact/(equivP eqfunP)/ffunP. Qed.

Lemma FFP2 f1 f2 : 
  [forall x : 'I_n, f1 x == f2 x] = all [fun x => f1 x == f2 x] (enum 'I_n).
Proof.
by apply/eqfunP/allP=> [eqf x he|eqf x]; apply/eqP/eqf; rewrite ?enumT.
Qed.

Definition f_inj (f : nat -> nat) : FFb := [ffun x => f (val x)].

Lemma FFP3 (f1 f2 : nat -> nat) :
  all [fun x => f1 x == f2 x] (iota 0 n) -> f_inj f1 = f_inj f2.
Proof.
move/allP=> /= hb; apply/FFP1; rewrite FFP2; apply/allP=> x hx /=.
by rewrite !ffunE; apply/hb; rewrite mem_iota ?ltn_ord.
Qed.

(* Exercise, derive bounded eq from f_inj f1 = f_inj f2 *)

End AllU.
```

The final lemma should indeed allow you reduce equality of functions to a computational, fully runnable Gallina function.

A simpler version of the above, and likely more useful to you is:

```
Lemma FFP n (f1 f2 : nat -> nat) :
  [forall x : 'I_n, f1 x == f2 x] = all [pred x | f1 x == f2 x] (iota 0 n).
Proof.
apply/eqfunP/allP=> eqf x; last by apply/eqP/eqf; rewrite mem_iota /=.
by rewrite mem_iota; case/andP=> ? hx; have /= -> := eqf (Ordinal hx).
Qed.
```

But it depends on how you (absent) condition on range restriction is specified.

After your edit, I think I should add a note on the more general topic of map equality, indeed you can define a more specific type of maps other than `A -> B` and then build a decision procedure.

Most typical map types [including the ones in the stdlib] will work, as long as they support the operation of "binding retrieval", so you can reduce equality to the check of finitely-many bound values.

In fact, the maps in Coq's standard library do already provide you such computational equality function.

Comment: Thank you, your answer together with gallais are stellar. I can now experiment without feeling completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a rather brutal solution which does not attempt to avoid doing the same case distinctions multiple times but it's fully automated.

We start with a tactic which inspects whether two integers are equal (using `Z.eqb`) and translates the results to a proposition which `omega` can deal with.

```
Ltac inspect_eq y x :=
  let p := fresh "p" in
  let q := fresh "q" in
  let H := fresh "H" in
  assert (p := proj1 (Z.eqb_eq x y));
  assert (q := proj1 (Z.eqb_neq x y));
  destruct (Z.eqb x y) eqn: H;
  [apply (fun p => p eq_refl) in p; clear q|
   apply (fun p => p eq_refl) in q; clear p].
```

We can then write a function which fires the first occurence of `i` it can find. This may introduce contradictory assumptions in the context e.g. if a previous match has revealed `x = 0` but we now call `inspect x 0`, the second branch will have both `x = 0` and `x <> 0` in the context. It will be automatically dismissed by `omega`.

```
Ltac fire_i x y := match goal with
  | [ |- context[i ?x' ?y' _ _] ] =>
    unfold i at 1; inspect_eq x x'; inspect_eq y y'; (omega || simpl)
end.
```

We can then put everything together: call functional extensionality twice, repeat `fire_i` until there's nothing else to inspect and conclude by `reflexivity` (indeed all the branches with contradictions have been dismissed automatically!).

```
Ltac eqFF :=
  let x := fresh "x" in
  let y := fresh "y" in
  intros;
  apply functional_extensionality; intro x;
  apply functional_extensionality; intro y;
  repeat fire_i x y; reflexivity.
```

We can see that it discharges your lemma without any issue:

```
Lemma foo_eq : foo = foo'.
Proof.
unfold foo, foo'; eqFF.
Qed.
```

[Here is a self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/32e07afd9d49d439e5791044591afa35) with all the imports and definitions.

Comment: Thank you, your answer together with ejgallegos constitute excellent ways of approaching the problem!